# Google Maps: why do I get referer-not-allowed-map-error?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an Android app (outside the Play Store) that uses a HTML page with a Javascript that calls Google Maps. I get a `referer-not-allowed-map-error` when creating the API as Android app. I need to set restrictions to NONE for this to work properly. The app is signed properly as debug.

Why is this? How can I restrict the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android app restriction is not valid for Google Maps JavaScript API. This restriction is only used with Google Maps Android SDK and Places Android SDK.

Have a look at the following document that explains which type of API key restriction you can use with Google Maps APIs

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem

In order to solve your issue, I would suggest checking the value of `window.location.href` in your HTML page when you load it from Web view in your Android app. This value will contain string that might be used as HTTP referrer restriction for Maps JavaScript API. Note that `file://` protocol requires special representation as explained in

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key-restrictions

I hope this helps!

Comment: I see. The idea of adding `file://` (or better `__file_url__//`) as a referrer is excellent. Thanks!!

Comment: I think the `file://` idea is not very useful after all. Adding a `console.log` to the javascript It shows `file:///android_asset/map.html`

Comment: @LuisA.Florit - did you ever have any additional luck with this?  I am having the same issue with my app using the Javascript API - trying to lock it down with the `file://` and wondering how effective it is.