# What is the file:// referrer for Google Javascript MAP API restriction

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, referrer

I need help understanding what file:// referrer for Google Javascript Maps API means and how it works?  See `NOTE` at the bottom of `Restrict the API Key` section https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Ultimately, I have a cordova/ionic app that I am loading google maps via the Javascript Maps API (not the SDK).  I want to lock down my maps API key to only be able to use from within my app but best I can tell the Javascript Maps API can only be restricted by domain referrer - until someone pointed out the Google now permits referrer by file://

But I don't understand how to make this work and I can't find anymore specific documentation about it.  Do I need a local file installed on my app with the sha-1 key or something? Or do I need to put the file-url-path to where the map is used within my app?  Or what....?

Comment: file:// is a file in the device's (or computer's) local file system (not served via a web server).

Comment: @geocodezip - I get that, but how can I use it to restrict the Maps API Key so its only valid from within my app?

Comment: I don't know that you can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps: why do I get referer-not-allowed-map-error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165198/google-maps-why-do-i-get-referer-not-allowed-map-error)

Comment: Just figure out what is the value of `window.location.href` in your app and use it to protect your API key following the API documentation.